# Java Applet Com Port

Tags: java, security, applet, serial-port

Any device with a Java Applet I want to respond to and send data via com port.Application works in appletviewer.When I work with any browser.This program gets stuck Security Barriers?
Do not have crossed them in any way?

Answer (score 2):

Digitally sign the applet, then convince the user to accept the code (click 'OK' when prompted).

If you find another way (besides the entirely impractical policy files), please let me know so I can raise a security bug with Oracle.